# Changing laravel pagination links to be over HTTPS

Tags: laravel

If you are on Heroku you may have noticed that when you have pagination links it comes out over HTTP. This is a problem because when you try to access that page, you get a Mixed Content error because those links are not in HTTPS. How do you solve this?

Issue:
[image]

Comment: Check what is value of `APP_URL` in `.env` file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this all you have to do is go into AppServiceProvider.php and in the boot method add the following: `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on');`

Comment: Can i mixed the solution? I have forceScheme set, trust all proxies set and your solution. The rest of the links generated just fine (with HTTPS) except pagination. I'm behind load balancer that terminates the SSL btw.

Answer (score 4):

This is a side-effect of Heroku's load balancing system. Heroku sets a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, but Laravel [needs some minor configuration](https://laravel-news.com/trusted-proxy) to process it properly. This is handled by the `fideloper/proxy` package (which is built into Laravel as of v5.5). First, publish the config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider"
```

Then, in the resulting `config/trustedproxy.php` file:

```
'proxies' => '*',
```

Your apps should correctly reflect the HTTP/HTTPS status now. (You'll also get the correct IP addresses for your users instead of the internal IPs of Heroku's load balancers, as an additional bonus.)

Comment: this is useful if you have ssl for load balancer and your app is running on port 80, thank you man client - SSL - load balancer - 80 - app

Comment: @UgurKazdal Yep! Glad it helped.